# How get that expression?

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to find out sign of $$\int_{-2}^2x^3\cdot2^x\,dx$$
I have a solution but I can't understand one step from it. So $$\int_{-2}^2x^3\cdot2^x\,dx=\int_{-2}^0x^3\cdot2^x\,dx + \int_0^2x^3\cdot2^x\,dx.$$ Let $$I_1 =\int_{-2}^0x^3\cdot2^x\,dx, \qquad I_2= \int_0^2x^3\cdot2^x\,dx.$$ After that in my book I have the following text: Assuming that $x=-t$ in $I_2$, we get that $$I=I_1+I_2=2\int_0^2x^3\cdot sh(x\ln2)\,dx.$$ Where does it come from? I don't understand.

Comment: If you just draw a picture of $x^32^x$ you will be able to see the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2^x=e^{\ln 2^x}=e^{x\ln 2}$$
Then $$e^{x\ln 2}-e^{-x\ln 2}=2\sinh(x\ln 2)$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac{d(2^x x^n)}{dx}=2^x\ln2\cdot x^n+2^x nx^{n-1}$$

If $\displaystyle I_m=\int 2^xx^m\ dx, I_0=?$

$$2^xx^n=\ln2\cdot I_n+n I_{n-1}\iff I_n=\dfrac{2^xx^n-nI_{n-1}}{\ln2}$$